# Change background color of the row or range if a particular cell value is equal to some text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

What I have:

```
1   Col A      Col B  Col C   Col D   Col E  Col F 
2
3  Approved    Text   Text    Text    Text   Text
4  Reject      Text   Text    Text    Text   Text
5  Pending     Text   Text    Text    Text   Text
```

What I want is :

1. If Column A value is equal to `Approved` then entire `row-3` should have a `green` background.
2. If Column A value is equal to `Reject` then entire `row-4` should have a `red` background.
3. If Column A value is equal to `Pending` then entire `row-5` should have a `amber` background.

How to change the background color of the row or range if a particular cell value is equal to some text?

Comment: The keyword is conditional formatting, in my Excel 2010 it's hidden under "Start" ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on Excel 2007:

[image: SO18355419 example]

Ie in Conditional Formatting create three separate rules, each with a formula like =$A1="Approved" and formatting to suit and with Applies to: a sensible maximum for the range to be formatted.